how to call a microservice with its eureka server registered application name in webclient in Spring Boot
In order to call other microservice in restTemplate we can use
restTemplate.getForObject("http://MICROSERVICE-NAME/service/order, OrderResponseDTO.class);

where MICROSERVICE-NAME is the name of microservice registered on eureka server
But If I try to do same using webclient I get java.net.UnknownHostException
    @Bean
    public WebClient getWebClient() {

        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://MICROSERVICE-NAME")
                .build();
    }


  webClient.get()
                .uri("/service/order")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(OrderResponseDTO.class);

So what is the correct way of achieving same thing using webclient. Also I cannot provide exact baseurl here As I set server.port=0 so everytime it will get different port
